# Ошибка вывода, связнная с fread()

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь осуществить запись и чтение в бинарном файле переменной Name типа string.

Функция записи:

```
    void Save(const char* Filename)
{
    if (this->Isbeing
    {
        int Namesize=this->Name.length();
        FILE *File;
        File = fopen(Filename,"ab");

        fwrite(&Namesize,sizeof(int),1,File);
        fwrite(&this->Name,Namesize,1,File);

        /// сохранение 8 значений типа long double (12 байт каждое)

        fclose(File);

        std::cout<<"Namesize: "<<Namesize<<std::endl;
    }
```

Функция чтения:

```
    int Load(const char* Filename, int Numberobject2, int Append2)
{
    int Namesize;
    FILE *File;
    File = fopen(Filename,"rb");
    fseek(File, 3*sizeof(int)+sizeof(long double)*8*Numberobject2+Append2,SEEK_SET);

    fread(&Namesize,sizeof(int),1,File);
    std::cout<<"NSZ: "<<Namesize<<std::endl;
    fread(&this->Name,Namesize,1,File);

    std::cout<<"N: "<<this->Name<<std::endl;  /// Здесь происходит ошибка и откладчик останавливает выполнение программы

    ///Чтение 8 значений типа long double, что были записаны ранее

    fclose(File);

    return Namesize;

}
```

Отладчик открывает окно "Call stack" при попытке вывести Name в функции load. В первой строке записано: std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<< , std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream >&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) ()

Во второй: object::Load(this=0xb12be0, Filename=0x44a333 <_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEESbIT_T0_T1_ERKS6_S8_+4498227> "save.dat", Numberobject2=0, Append2=0)

В третьей: main().

Чтение значений с типом long double и int происходит без проблем. Если же запустить в обычном режиме, то программа может прекратить работу после

```
    std::cout<<"N: "<<this->Name<<std::endl; /// Функция Load()
```

, выполнить функцию Load() присвоив пустое имя (при этом функция в дальнейшем выполняется нормально), дойти до конца функции и прекратить работу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `string` предполагается по сути массивом символов, расположенным по адресу самого объекта. Это **далеко** не так.

Пожалуй, проще всего отработать примерно так (обработка ошибок опущена):

```
string read(FILE* f)
{
    int len;
    fread(&len,sizeof(len),1,f);
    char * buf = new char[len];
    fread(buf,len,1,f);
    string result(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return result;
}

void write(FILE* f, const string& s)
{
    int len = s.length()+1;
    fwrite(&len,sizeof(len),1,f);
    fwrite(s.c_str(),len,1,f);
}
```

Т.е. записать - длину и содержимое строки как нуль-завершенной, прочитать - сначала длину, выделить буфер, считать в него саму строку, создать из нее `string`.

Только вот смешение в одной программе `string` и `FILE` - дизайн, гм, несколько сомнительный.

Comment: Зачем 2 раза выделять память? Можно вызвать `string::resize` и работать со `string::front` или `string::operator[]` при заполнении. Хотя, справедливости ради, стоит заметить, что непрерывность данных в `std::string` не гарантировалась до `c++11`, но по факту - везде была.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, я же сразу написал - _проще всего_, в смысле - понятнее всего. По вопросу видно, что человек совершенно не представляет себе (даже концептуально), не только как реализуется строка, но и что такое объект вообще... Поэтому и расписал попроще.

Но, конечно же, вы совершенно правы.

Answer (score -1):

В приведенном коде в функции `fread` и `fwrite` передается указатель на переменную типа `std::string` в предположении, что будет производиться запись/чтение в/из содержимое строки. Однако делать предположения о реализации типа `string` нельзя.

В низкоуровневые функций типа `fread` необходимо передавать указатели на массивы, содержащие данные используемого класса (если этот класс предоставляет такую возможность, т.е. гарантируется, что `&a[i] == (&a[0] + i)`). Для чтения многие библиотечные классы предоставляют метод `data`. Для записи же в такие классы может использоваться конструкция `&a[0]`. Необходимо проверять возможность использования этих конструкций для выбранного класса (для `std::string` такая возможность гарантируется начиная со стандарта c++11).

Comment: Изменять значения по указателю, который возвращает .data(), можно **только начиная с C++11**. Для более ранних версий запись чего-то в .data - UB!

Comment: @gbg, `data()` возвращает `const charT*`. О каком вообще изменении может быть речь?

Comment: @gbg Верное замечание. Спасибо!